# Mysql how to count the days between from and to date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Suppose I have

```
     > ID               FromDate                         ToDate 
     > --              --------                         -------
     > 1               '2013-12-14 00:00:00'         '2013-12-23 00:00:00'
     > 2               '2013-12-24 00:00:00'         '2013-12-31 00:00:00'
```

For my scenario, User searching from  '2013-12-14 00:00:00'  to '2013-12-29 00:00:00'

Total days is " 15". 
I want output something like this

```
 > ID                  FromDate                         ToDate                countdays
 > --              --------                         -------
 > 1               '2013-12-14 00:00:00'         '2013-12-23 00:00:00'         9
 > 2               '2013-12-24 00:00:00'         '2013-12-31 00:00:00'         6
```

9+6=15

1st row fromdate and todate are between the user fromdate and todate  so countdays is 9
2nd row  i want count days from  '2013-12-24 00:00:00'  till  '2013-12-29 00:00:00'  How can i do this with mysql?

Comment: If you know that the times are always midnight, just subtract the earlier day from the latter, and add 1.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens. You are assuming the user searches between two dates within one single month. Not really a valid answer to the question.

Comment: @PeteR:No; SQL date-time types store the data in a floating point representation where the integer part is the day (counting from the start of the epoch) and the fractional part is the fraction of the day. I have used several SQL dialects and this has always been true in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL** 
   Select ID, FromDate, ToDate , DATEDIFF(DAY, ToDate, FromDate) As Count From TableName

**Syntax in SQL  :**

> DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

**MYSQL**

```
Select ID, FromDate, ToDate , DATEDIFF(ToDate, FromDate) As Count From TableName
```

**Example:**

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)

DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
        -> -31
```

Source : [Date Difference documentation by MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT t.*, 
       DATE(LEAST(t.todate, s.todate)) 
     - DATE(GREATEST(t.fromdate, s.fromdate)) countdays
  FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT '2013-12-14 00:00:00' fromdate,
         '2013-12-29 00:00:00' todate
) s
 WHERE s.fromdate BETWEEN t.fromdate AND t.todate
    OR s.todate   BETWEEN t.fromdate AND t.todate
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fb7a/2)** demo